# Activity fails in onRestoreInstanceState() - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an ArrayList of an object. I am trying to save it as mentioned in the below code. When I try to fetch the object in onRestoreInstanceState() I m getting NullPointerException. Kindly point me where the code needs correction

```
  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); 
    Log.i("MemoryGame", "onSaveInstanceState");   
    outState = new Bundle(); 
    outState.putSerializable("saveMemory", (Serializable) memory);
  } 

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("MemoryGame", "onRestoreInstanceState");    
    ArrayList<Memory> retrievedMemory =  (ArrayList<Memory>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("saveMemory"); 
    Log.i("MemoryGame", "onRestoreInstanceState : memory " + retrievedMemory.get(0).getPictureName()); 
  }
```

### Logcat

```
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free/kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.MemoryGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.MemoryGame.onRestoreInstanceState(MemoryGame.java:2135)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:900)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1130)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
03-29 16:26:58.047: E/AndroidRuntime(16281): ... 11 more
```

Comment: IS your savedInstanceState null?

Comment: The value in savedInstanceState is  
Bundle[{android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[{android:views=android.util.SparseArray@41bb2890}]}]

Comment: @iappmaker have you got the solution??

Comment: No. Expecting some advice

Comment: is your Memory  implement serializable

Comment: @iappmaker posted my answer check like that..you will get..

Comment: No it is not implementing it

Comment: i think you have to use putParcebleArrayListExtra .

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29

Comment: @iappmaker have you checked like that..if you are not getting let me know

Comment: It is working but the object is having different values

Comment: @iappmaker That means it may be your logic problem.in Bundle what you will store that only it return

Comment: After destory() in this Activity the control returns back to onRestoreInstanceState first or to onCreate()

Comment: @iappmaker onCreate() call first then after only onRestoreState

Comment: @iappmaker checkout this more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29

Comment: ok I got it . In onCreate() I have to check if savedInstanceState != null ?

Comment: @iappmaker yes like that also you can check and get the data..

Comment: But the variable savedInstanceState is not visible in onCreate(). How do the onCreate know that it is a reentry

Comment: @iappmaker onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) in that savedInstanceState is the bundle method will give you the value..

Comment: Yeah I tried that now in onCreate. But again hitting NPE  in retrievedMemory.get(0).getPictureName());    


  if(savedInstanceState != null){
      ArrayList<Memory> retrievedMemory =  (ArrayList<Memory>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("saveMemory"); 
   Log.i("MemoryGame", "onCreate   retrievedMemory.get(0).getPictureName()  : " + retrievedMemory.get(0).getPictureName());    
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this line you are not getting data

```
outState = new Bundle();
```

dont create object evary time..create only when the Bundle is null..so check like this..

```
 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); 
        Log.i("MemoryGame", "onSaveInstanceState");   
        if (outState==null) {
            outState = new Bundle();
        }
        outState.putSerializable("saveMemory", (Serializable) memory);
      }
```

That too your `Memory` class must implements `Serializable` Interface like.

```
public class Memory implements Serializable
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely support. I got it with your clear steps

Comment: The 'checking for null' suggestion in answer is wrong. The bundle that is passed as parameter to `Activity#onSaveInstanceState` will never be null.